# Original of bounced in place track is inaudible in Logic Pro

Tags: bounce

In Logic Pro, when I bounce in place a sample and then delete the bounced track the original track is inaudible. What do I do to make it work again?

Comment: Please consider adding some detail to this question. As we cannot see over your shoulder, this is unanswerable.

Comment: Oh I thought this was a Logic Pro forum.

Comment: No, this is not only a forum, it is not dedicated to Logic Pro, or in fact any product or vendor. Please read the [about] and [ask] page again for an explanation of how Stack Exchange works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha... the actual sample is muted even though the track isn't.